# My RPi0 W crashes

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, kernel, raspbian-lite

My RasPi 0 W Crashes while updating and upgrading after i newly flashed the SD card with 2019-07-10-raspbian-buster-lite.img

my putty console:

```
login as: pi
pi@192.168.2.119's password:
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.57+ #1244 Thu Jul 4 18:42:50 BST 2019 armv6l

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sun Sep  1 13:16:54 2019

SSH is enabled and the default password for the 'pi' user has not been changed.
This is a security risk - please login as the 'pi' user and type 'passwd' to set a new password.

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo reboot
Get:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease [25.2 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf Packages [13.0 MB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster/main armhf Packages [222 kB]
Fetched 13.3 MB in 27s (500 kB/s)
Reading package lists... 99%
Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep  1 13:20:43 ...
 kernel:[  326.748148] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] ARM

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep  1 13:20:43 ...
 kernel:[  326.859491] Process kworker/u2:2 (pid: 108, stack limit = 0xaef81872)

Message from syslogd@raspberrypi at Sep  1 13:20:43 ...
 kernel:[  326.866990] Stack: (0xd9183b40 to 0xd9184000)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
12 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and my hdmi output from the pi : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrJYT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

From the putty console output you have given it seems not to be a fault of the upgrade. You get a **kernel Oops** just on reading the package list from `apt update`. The `apt full-upgrade` will come after that. Updating the package list will only get it from the internet and write it to the SD Card, nothing more. There weren't made any changes to the operating system that may cause the Oops. But continuing with the full-upgrade will increase the problems.

The first idea is that there is a problem with writing to the SD Card. You should try a new SD Card, flash it and boot. Then login and reboot to be on the save side after the root partition has been expanded to the size of the new SD Card. Then I would do the upgrade step by step with a reboot to check where the problem is:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```